# Is this the case of data leakage?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model

Let's say, I have the dataframe with numerical features A, B, C. I do not have the target variable but I extract the target variable Y from the features A, B, and C. E.g. 
`If values A<0.1*sum (A,B,C) and B 0.1*sum (A,B,C) and C<0.1*sum (A,B,C) then Y=1 or else Y=0`. 
Now I have features A,B,C and target variable Y for which I train model to predict Y. Is this data leakage? Is there anything wrong with this method?

Comment: If you know the rule for the target variable, why train a model?

Comment: Exactly, seems that you can determine Y analytically using a formula. Why bother with machine learning?